# Find pod rescheduling events in Kubernetes / GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Kubernetes via Google Container Engine.

I have a deployment object with 5 replicas, running for 12 days. It appears that Kubernetes rescheduled my pod a few times in the last 12 days. Is there an event log that I could look up to see the exact history of that deployment object, when it rescheduled pods, etc..?

I poked around in both Google Cloud Logging (which is enabled for my cluster) and `kubectl events` but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody arriving here in 2020, and using GKE - the Events are indeed garbage collected approximately every hour according to [K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/events-stackdriver/) ("... events are removed one hour after the last occurrence."), but in modern GKE installations, all events are logged to Stackdriver and can be found by searching [the Google Cloud Logging service](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) for something like:

```
logName="projects/[project-name]/logs/events"
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.location="us-east1"
resource.labels.cluster_name="production"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an event history for a particular pod:

```
kubectl describe <pod>
```

It's possible they are gone though, this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4432) suggests that events are garbage collected, but I'm not clear for how long.

Comment: This shows no events for all my pods. Perhaps the events are too old?

Comment: Updated my answer, looks like kubernetes does garbage collect events

Comment: Thanks. Too bad, those are really useful events.